# UITable cell selection in a SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have a UISplitViewController with a Table View for navigation. It's similar to the Mail app. When you click on a table view in portrait mode, the popup hides itself. When you click on the nav bar to get the popup back, the selected item no longer appears selected. How can make this item appear selected without re-selecting the item? (just like in the mail app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution that works, but it's frustratingly hacky. I have to call selectRowAtIndexPath twice. It seems that cellForRowAtIndexPath is invalidating the selection made in viewWillAppear. It still needs to be called in viewDidAppear, however, so the view scrolls to the proper position before cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSIndexPath *selected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    _selectedRow = selected.row;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_selectedRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //initialize cell code here...

    if (indexPath.row == _selectedRow) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your viewDidLoad method, do you call

`self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;` ?

This is how Xcode's SplitView template does it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have by any change a

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the RootViewController ?

Comment: No. That's not called anywhere as far as I can tell, but its behaving as if it is. When I call selectCellAtIndexPath in viewDidAppear, or cell.selected = YES, it's deselected immediately. Do you know where this might be called?

Answer (score 0):

For your table view controller, is `-viewWillAppear:` called before the pop-up is displayed? If so, you could write it as so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:<indexPath>
                                animated:animated
                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Obviously, replace `<indexPath>` with the proper index path and set the scroll position how you want it. You may also want to pass `NO` instead of `animated` to make it appear like it was selectd before the view appeared.

Comment: That didn't work. Something is deselecting items tableview after viewDidAppear is called.